# Is it even possible to load/render an SVG file on a Mesh?

Tags: svg, three.js, 3d

([Using SVG as scalable texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860515/using-svg-as-scalable-texture)) this Post represents the same Issue I have.

I am trying to map my worldmap.svg on a Sphere. When trying to map is as usual, it loses its property of an SVG file and has pixels. I have tried to use SVGLoader. It did work, but the worldmap is in 2D. 
Someone in the comments refered to the SVGRenderer. But it didn't change anything.
So is it correct that it is IMPOSSIBLE to map the SVG file on a Mesh without getting pixels?
If it is possible, it would be great if someone could share an example as I couldn't find one.

Comment: Not much is impossible if you have the skill  but in practice, what you're trying to do may be difficult. I would probably approach this by importing the svg into blender and wrapping it on a sphere in blender and then exporting as .glb, and loading that into threejs.

Comment: You can load an svg in threejs but there aren't really tools to just wrap the resulting line vector geometry around a sphere. That's the hard part since you would have to subdivide all the lines so that they could wrap around the sphere smoothly without looking janky.